# Error - declared but not defined :static and static inline function

Tags: c, static, inline

I am writing a static inline function using vc++ / Microsoft visual studio editor. My code is written as below

**File main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "foo.h"

void main()
{       
    int32_t a = { 0 }, b = 3, c = 4, d = {0};

    foo(b, c, &d);
    a = a + d;
    printf("a = %10d\n", a);

}
```

**File foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "foo.h"

static inline int32_t foo(int32_t b, int32_t c, int32_t* d)
{
    return(*d = (b + c) >> 1);
}
```

**File foo.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static inline int32_t foo(int32_t b, int32_t c, int32_t* d);
```

When I build the code, I am getting an error

```
error C2129: static function 'int32_t foo(int32_t,int32_t,int32_t *)' declared but not defined.
```

**Functions will be inline if they are used in same file but what happens if all the inline function moves to header file . How can i make function foo() static inline function?**

I don't understand where is the problem/what is the concept behind static inline function across files.

Comment: If you declare a function static in some file, then it must have its definition in that file. Since you have used the preprocessor directive `#include foo.h` so basically it will be replaced by whatever is present in the file `foo.h` at the time of preprocessing, i.e before compilation.

Comment: And anyway you cannot use a `static` function in one .c file from another .c file. Remove `static`.

Comment: So you basically have a file `main.c` and at the top of file you have a function declaration `static inline int32_t foo(int32_t b, int32_t c, int32_t* d);` but the definition of function is not present in the file, and the declaration states that the function `foo` is static, so it must be present in the file `main.c`

Comment: Remove all `static` and `inline`, then your code will compile.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Is it necessary to remove `inline`?

Comment: @ShahFahad yes, see the answer below, but forget the `#define` part of the answerr it's wrong.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I assumed he wants the inline behavior, why is it wrong ?

Comment: Functions will be inline if they are used in same file but what happens if all the inline function moves to header file and I make static inline ?

Comment: The matter is pretty complicated, this may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function

Comment: Put the `static inline` definition of function `foo()` in the header `foo.h`.  Then it is available for use where the header is included.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, In fact , I am doing (pls see the code ) unfortunately it is not working !!!

Comment: The code you show in the header has a `static inline` declaration.  I mean put the definition (currently in `function.c`) into the header (and remove it from`function.c` — if you even need `function.c` at all after this).  You won't need the declaration in the header once you have the definition in there instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -Thanks a lot for your suggestion, This works well. High Five